# JSTL Calculate total of bean values

Tags: java, jstl

after a loop runs and populates a data table I want to calculate the totals of the columns and display them on the last row.

This is my code to populate the table...I need to build the last row:

```
<table class="data_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Source Of Issues</th>
    <th>First Issues</th>
    <th>second Issues</th>
    <th>Changes</th>
  </tr>

  <c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="loopCount">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="foobar">${bean.sorCode}</a></td>
      <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.firstissue}'
                             type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
      <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.secondissue}'
                             type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
      <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.changes}'
                             type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<c:set var="sum" value="${0}"/>     
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="loopCount">
  <c:set var="total" value="${bean.actualLabor + bean.plannedLabor}"/>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="foobar">${bean.sorCode}</a></td>
    <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.firstissue}' 
                           type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
    <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.secondissue}'
                           type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
    <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${changes}'
                           type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
  </tr>
  <c:set var="sum" value="${sum + changes}"/>      
</c:forEach>

<fmt:formatNumber value='${sum}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' />
```

Comment: first line inside loop, second outside. right?

Comment: I need the total of the column

Comment: can you tell me, what you get? an exception? or calculation is wrong?

Comment: I updated your answer, with mine under yours....You were adding 2 different columns. I needed a row of totals that shows the total for each column   You also changed the variable name from sum to total

Comment: Your framework was correct though

Answer (score -1):

```
    <table class="data_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Source Of Issues</th>
        <th>First Issues</th>
        <th>second Issues</th>
        <th>Changes</th>
    </tr>
    <c:set var="plannedSum" value="${0}"/>
    <c:set var="actualSum" value="${0}"/> 
    <c:set var="changesSum" value="${0}"/>   
    <c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="loopCount">
    <c:set var="plannedSum" value="${plannedSum + bean.firstissue}"/>
    <c:set var="actualSum" value="${actualSum + bean.secondissue}"/>  
    <c:set var="changesSum" value="${changesSum + bean.changes}"/> 
        <tr>
            <td><a href="foobar">${bean.sorCode}</a></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.firstissue}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.secondissue}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${bean.changes}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
       </tr>
     </c:forEach>
     <tr>
            <td><a>Totals</a></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${plannedSum}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${actualSum}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
            <td class="right"><fmt:formatNumber value='${changesSum}' type="currency" groupingUsed='true' /></td>
    </tr>


</table>
```